# Laravel artisan command php artisan make:Import is not defined

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to run this command in laravel 5.5 but is not working.

```
php artisan make:Import ImportUsers --model=User
```

showing these statements

```
   Command "make:Import" is not defined.

  Did you mean one of these?
  make:auth
  make:command
  make:controller
  make:event
  make:exception
  make:factory
  make:job
  make:listener
  make:mail
  make:middleware
  make:migration
  make:model
  make:module
  make:notification
  make:policy
  make:provider
  make:request
  make:resource
  make:rule
  make:seeder
  make:test
```

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Please try: `php artisan make:import ImportUsers --model=User`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with the capital letter .

```
php artisan make:Import ImportUsers --model=User
```

You should use make:import instead of make:Import

```
php artisan make:import ImportUsers --model=User
```

I think you missing out something which is mentioned here  .
[introducing-laravel-excel](https://medium.com/maatwebsite/introducing-laravel-excel-3-1-e478502bf92e)

Comment: used the lowercase letter in import word as showing the same error

Comment: @Zunaid have you installed [laravel-excel](https://laravel-excel.com/)?

Comment: Yes, I installed the laravel-excel

Comment: @Zunaid I have modified my question . take a look at it

Answer (score 1):

To run this command you have to install the dependencies of the package using the following steps.

1. Run this command
   **composer require maatwebsite/excel**
2. Goto config/app.php file and add the two lines inside the respective arrays.

   'providers' => [

   ```
              .......

              .......
              Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class
   ```

   ],

   'aliases' => [

   ```
             .......
             .......
             'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,
   ```

   ],
3. Execute the vendor publish command.

   **php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider"**

After that, you will be able to run the command
**php artisan make:import ImportUsers --model=User**

You can find the complete tutorial here:
https://www.positronx.io/laravel-import-expert-excel-and-csv-file-tutorial-with-example/